# Spotfire Add several columns with a custom expression

Tags: spotfire

I would like add several columns in a Bar Chart in Y with a custom expression. I have several columns which begin with "HB" or "PASS". 
Their number change as well as their name every time I refresh the table. But HB or PASS remains in column name.

I tried to use this expression :

```
Sum($map("[$csearch([pvtable],"PASS*")]",","))/Count([SUBLOT_ID])
```

or

```
$map("[$csearch([pvtable],"PASS*")]",","))
```

If I have only one column with PASS or HB in key word it works, but not if I have several columns with this key words in their name.

It's an example of my datas. They are in percentage.

```
LOT_ID   SUBLOD_ID WL_PART_CNT PASS_HB1 PASS_HB2   HB5    HB10   HB13   HB25
Q640123    01         3841       86          11   0.25   0.5    0.25    2
Q640123    05         3841       96           3      0     1      0     0
Q640123    10         3841       80          12      0     2      4     2
Q640123    16         3841       40          50      1     1      4     4
Q640123    22         3841       85           5      9    0.5    0.5    0
Q640345    01         3841       86          11   0.25   0.5    0.25    2
Q640345    05         3841       96           3      1     0      0     0
Q640345    10         3841       80          12      0     2      4     2
Q640345    16         3841       40          50      1     1      4     4
Q640345    22         3841       85           5      9    0.5    0.5    0
```

I want to put LOT_ID in X, and PASS together in Y. I don't want to color my bar chart but I would like a result like this. One bar chart with all columns PASS and an other with all columns HB.

[image]

This bar chart represent HB.

Thank you for your help, regards, Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `$map` function, only the `$csearch`

```
Sum($csearch([pvtable],"PASS*")) /Count([SUBLOT_ID])
```

**EDIT**

After looking at your test data, you will need to map the values.

```
$map("sum([$csearch([pvtable],"PASS*")])","+"),$map("sum([$csearch([pvtable],"HB*")])","+")
```

Then, on your `X-AXIS` you will need: `<[LOT_ID] NEST [Axis.Default.Names]>`

Comment: I tried your solution, but I have the same problem. It works with one HB or PASS but not with many. And in the center of the graph it is written "Please specify an aggregation method."

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set @LaurentCesaro   I did this with test data and it was fine so perhaps it's to do with your data or coloring trellis or.... etc

Comment: @LaurentCesaro See the edit above. Thanks for the sample data. I would delete your answer, and add this information to your original post (you can edit your original post)

Comment: No worries at all @LaurentCesaro and no need to apologize! Hopefully that second expression works for you. I tested it locally.

Comment: Thank you it works, I can add all my columns, but in cumutative I am not to 100%. Do you have it ?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to calculate @LaurentCesaro, why would you think your calculation would be 100%? Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the columns PASS and HB it is a percentage. If one makes the cumulation of its percentages one must find 100%. SUBLOT_ID corresponds to a plate and HB has error messages. For example in the first line for PASS_HB1 I have 86.10%. That means I have 86.10% of the plate that is correct. So in total I have to get 100%. Tell me if I'm not clear. Regards.

Comment: @LaurentCesaro I can't see how any of your rows or columns would add up to 100%, with any grouping. Can you show an example of the grouping which would add up to 100%? I'm assuming this won't be possible as the percentages were calculated before you pivoted the table.

Comment: I'm sorry it's hard to explain. I did a dcast in a script R on my table. In the picture in my post you can see a cumutative of percentage for HB. But if I complete with PASS_HB I should have 100%

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to follow @LaurentCesaro. SUBLOD_ID 1,10,16 don't add up to 100 for me. They are 98.03, 102, and 102 respectively for each LOT_ID

Comment: Thank you really much for your help @scsimon!! I had found a solution. I added brackets around map and divided by Count([SUBLOT_ID]). Like that I obtained my results in percentage without exceeding 100%. Have a nice day !